# Measure words for music

Tags: measure-word

I'm aware of the construct: 一首歌曲。

However, what's the difference between the following 声音 constructs?

- 一张音乐
- 一曲音乐
- 一段音乐

Comment: （小马词典：音乐 yīn yuè music; CL:张,曲,段）
dictionary entries for quoted measure words may help：
曲： song ； tune ； melody 张：（量）与成张的事物搭配：两～纸｜三～床｜一～嘴｜一～弓。段：<量>
（部分） section ； segment ； part ； paragraph

Comment: also note:
场<量>
（用于文娱体育活动） for sports and recreation 
(for music actually played)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 一张音乐 is short for 一张音乐专辑 (a music album) or 一张音乐CD （a music CD), etc., in which cases the noun at the end of the expression is flat (LP disc, CD) and can take 张 as classifier.
- 一曲音乐 is a 'tuneful' of music or a 'melody-ful' of music, is also translated as 'a piece of music', I am just guessing but this could mean a piece of music which consists of at least one melody or theme, i.e. a length enough to unfold the melody or theme, or maybe longer.
- 一段音乐 is a piece of music, whatever that means in English or Chinese, usually a complete piece or a complete section of a larger opus.

@S.Rhee mentioned 场 which is a classifier for concerts if it is used in connection with music, e.g. 一场音乐会.